# Proving number of edges in $F = n - k$

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, induction, trees

So if we let $F = (V,E)$ be a forest with $n$ vertices and $k$ connected components (trees), how can I prove that the number of edges in $F = n - k$ ?

I was thinking of using induction, but I'm super lost. Can anyone guide me through this step by step? Would really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We note a tree $T$ with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges. So let $F = \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} T_{i}$ be the forest- a union of trees. Let $n_{i}$ be the number of vertices in each tree. So we have:

$|V(F)| = \sum_{i=1}^{k} n_{i} = n$

Since each component of the forest is a tree, we have $n_{i} - 1$ edges for $T_{i}$, giving us:

$|E(F)| = \sum_{i=1}^{k} (n_{i} - 1) = n - k$.

Comment: What is that F = U thing? I've never used notation like that. It's for an entry level algorithms and data structures class

Comment: It's a union series. Basically, $F = T_{1} \cup T_{2} \cup T_{3} \cup ... \cup T_{k}$, or a union of disjoint trees.

Comment: Alright and the "|V(F)|" is obviously indicating absolute value for that function, correct?

Comment: Can I leave the absolute value signs out?

Comment: The absolute value signs denote set cardinality, not absolute value. So $|V(F)|$ denotes the number of vertices. Of course, in graph theory, $V, E$ are commonly abused to denote the number of vertices/edges respectively as well as the sets of vertices/edges respectively. I like to use $V(G), E(G)$ to denote the vertex/edge sets of the graph and $|V(G)|, |E(G)|$ to denote cardinality. Check with your professor before abusing notation.

Comment: @ml0105Okay well keep in mind that this is for a basic computer science class, so is there anyway to make this perhaps a little more simpler and make it a proof by induction, and not have the overly complicated math terms being used?

Comment: I'd say the proof is pretty straight-forward, and it sounds like you're getting lost in notation. A forest is a collection of trees, right? Each tree has $n_{i}$ vertices and $n_{i} - 1$ edges, right? So we just add up the vertices and edges of each tree, right? If we have $k$ trees, the result follows. Induction really doesn't make sense here. Theoretical CS (data and algorithm analysis, theory of computation, etc.) is very mathematical, so you'll get a lot of math terminology here. Let me know if I can help you work through it more though.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way of thinking about this problem:

We know that an $n$ node tree has $n-1$ edges.  If you now want to convert this $n$ node tree to a $k$-tree forest, you have to remove $k-1$ edges from it.

So the number of edges in a $k$-tree forest with $n$ nodes would be:  $n-1-(k-1) = n-k$